# Terminology for one-to-one, many-to-one relationships concepts?

Tags: terminology

Some data is structured so there is only one piece of information that can be associated with an entity.  For example, a table with columns `(id, name, phone)` implies that each `id` has one `name` and one `phone` number.

Some data is structured such that there can be multiple repeated pieces of information associated with an entity.  For example, multiple keywords can be associated with an entity by repeating rows in a table `(id, keyword)`.  We commonly refer to this as a 1-many relationship.

Are there "non-database" words to describe these concepts?

Comment: For basic outline purposes, using the spreadsheet metaphor for table/entity/relation is quite useful. Give as a basic example a sheet with people (id, fname, lname, addr...) and then a sheet with their phone numbers (work, home, mobile...) related by the id field. 1-1 and 1-many are relatively easy concepts for people to grasp - why not use the correct terms?

Comment: @Vérace, I think these concepts predate relational db systems, and I'm interested in knowing what they were called, or if other domains use different terminology (for example, in patent jargon, they often say "plurality"). It might also serve a practical purpose as I would like to say "this is concept X, which we're implementing as a 1-many relationship."

Comment: "This is a 1-many concept which we're implementing as a 1-many relationship"? :-) Seriously though, you might want to check out Ted Codd's seminal paper " "A relational model of data for large shared data banks" which can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd). I don't think that the plurality to which you refer exists, at least in this area. I think that those dealing with data (even the most clueless) would have a grasp of 1-1, 1-many, many-many?

Comment: Consider this data structure: (item=statue, location=kitchen, attributes=(beautiful,expensive,fragile)).I'm curious about what these "relationships" were called previously, or in other systems. I've been familiar with Codd since 1984.

Comment: I think that prior to the formulation of database theory, there is no reason that I can think of that the structure you propose wouldn't have been used "as-is" - Codd based his work on relational algebra which dates from well before Codd's work (the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) is wrong!) - Codd applied RA to data"banks", he did **NOT** invent it. I don't really see what you're driving at - any 12 year old could understand the concepts we've been discussing - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to know the terminology used for this concept in other domains. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: I'm trying to remember what terms we used when I briefly worked in the fashion industry - notorious for the number of SKUs. Skirt, style =  pleated, colour = blue, fabric = cotton... the word attribute does spring to mind, but maybe that's my dba bias - fashion and other fields may use terms such as "traits", "properties", "features", "qualities" and "characters". I seem to remember the more fashion-victim types using the term "features" of the garment. HTH.

Comment: A one to one relationship can be called univocal. Not sure how you can call one-to-many or many-to-many relationships...